# Serial Port not working () on Arduino in JetBrains CLion

Tags: arduino-uno, clion, jetbrains-ide

Code works fine when tested on Arduino Uno, (editing delay(x) affects the led),
 but I get this error and Serial Port Monitor does not show anything.

Error in CLion Event Log is:

```
Error running Unnamed: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Nikhil Verma\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\4b320303\4b320303\Debug\summer.elf" (in directory "C:\Users\Nikhil Verma\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\4b320303\4b320303\Debug"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ArduinoToolchain.cmake)
set(PROJECT_NAME summer)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_BOARD uno)
set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_PORT COM1)
set(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}_SKETCH summer.ino)
generate_arduino_firmware(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
```

summer.ino

```
 #include <Arduino.h>
  void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println("Hi");
    digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    delay(7000);
    digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Configuration:

[image]

Log of Messaged Build :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.2.4\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\Users\Nikhil Verma\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\4b320303\4b320303\Debug" --target upload -- -j 8
[ 89%] Built target uno_CORE
[100%] Built target summer

        avrdude.exe: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude.exe: Device signature = 0x1e950f
avrdude.exe: reading input file "C:/Users/Nikhil Verma/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/4b320303/4b320303/Debug/summer.hex"
avrdude.exe: writing flash (2370 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.54s

avrdude.exe: 2370 bytes of flash written
avrdude.exe: reading input file "C:/Users/Nikhil Verma/.CLion12/system/cmake/generated/4b320303/4b320303/Debug/summer.eep"
avrdude.exe: writing eeprom (0 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% -0.00s

avrdude.exe: 0 bytes of eeprom written

avrdude.exe done.  Thank you.

[100%] Built target summer-upload
[100%] Built target upload

"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\CLion 1.2.4\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build "C:\Users\Nikhil Verma\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\4b320303\4b320303\Debug" --target summer -- -j 8
[ 89%] Built target uno_CORE
[100%] Built target summer
```

CMake Toolchain:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: did you solve the issue? I stumbled upon exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. 
The solution was to not click on the run (green play) button, but to click on build on the top right to run upload.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have enabled the **Debug** configuration in your tool, and your tool is *trying to execute the Arduino Binary* directly on your machine:

```
Error running Unnamed: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Nikhil Verma\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\4b320303\4b320303\Debug\summer.elf" (in directory "C:\Users\Nikhil Verma\.CLion12\system\cmake\generated\4b320303\4b320303\Debug"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I suggest you to modify your *IDE configuration* to skip this step, and *upload* the code to the device instead.

**EDIT**: I use [this approach](https://abrushforeachkeyboard.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/arduino-moving-to-makefile-projects/) for setting up the **Makefile** of all my projects, though since you are on Windows the configuration might change.